# Exist any Obj-c library to integration with paypal?

Tags: objective-c, payment-gateway

I wonder if exist a pre-made objective-c library to work with paypal, including with credit-cards.

My google search not get returns (I look for objective-c paypal)

Also, if exist other librarys for common gateways....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal code for iOS, get it from [x.com](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile)

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to go through your application, however, you could use WebKit to integrate a web view that connects to PayPal. That way, everything can be contained within the application but you would still work with PayPal the way they want you to work with them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, because they want you to go to their site. If you could just supply the data through a framework users couldn't trust Paypal.